# Should I write "said someone" or "said by someone"

Tags: meaning, grammaticality

What is more applicable when writing "said someone" or "said by someone"
e.g. "said Elon Musk" or "said by Elon musk"

Comment: We need more context. Both are applicable, depending on the context. `"Our future is bright", said Elon Musk` is OK, while `"Our future is bright" is a phrase once said by Elon Musk` is also OK.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the context,

> "Our future is bright" said Elon Musk

is correct and

> "Our future is bright" said by Elon Musk

is not, but

> "Our future is bright" is a phrase once said by Elon Musk

would be correct and

> "Our future is bright" is a phrase once said Elon Musk

would not be!